# Is there a website to lookup barcodes?

Tags: iphone, android, nokia, barcode, qr-code

I know there's a http://www.upcdatabase.com/ website that allows you to lookup barcodes. This website however does not return anything for thousands of normal household items. I have seen free apps on mobile phones that can do this and list the exact product name along with price comparison.

Does anyone know of good websites (even commercial ones) that have a good/reliable database that one could use for lookups?

Comment: This was a software development question as data collection is part of the 'development' phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zxing is the library that lets you decode the barcode into a number. It doesn't keep a database of what # links to which products. [Google Product Search](http://www.google.com/products) is a good place to start. [Etilize](http://www.etilize.com/index.html) provides a paid service for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

about about zxing? http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx